# How to include the Account Team object's fields in a report that includes Account records

Tags: apex, reporting, administration

I tried using the standard report type - Account with Account Teams.
But the fields for the Account Team Object related to the Accounts does not appear in the list of fields to include in the report.
How can I include the fields from Account Teams ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have [accountTeams](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/set-up-account-teams) enabled in your org? The "team member info & territory info" fields wouyld be available in report only if the accountTeams are enabled.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the issue. Although there are related account team records, account team is not enabled in setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see the account team object's fields in the report if you have AccountTeams enabled in your org.

> 1. From Setup, enter Account Teams in the Quick Find box, and select Account Teams.
> 2. Click Enable Account Teams.Select the Account Teams Enabled checkbox and click Save.

[Reference](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/set-up-account-teams)

Org with AccountTeams enabled:
[image]

Org without AccountTeams enabled:
[image]